# Symfony2 form - setParameter claims that the variable is undefined

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form in my symfony2 project where I am adding a new form element to the builder:

```
$builder->add('section', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'SciForumVersion2Bundle:Section',
            'label' => 'Section',
            'property' => 'name',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                ->where('s.conference = conference')
                ->setParameter('conference', $conference);
            },
    ));
```

And the $conference variable comes from the controller and I am setting this variable in the FormType:

```
private $conference;

public function __construct($conference)
{
    $this->conferenceObject = $conference;
}
```

But then I am getting the error message:

```
ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined variable: conference in ....
```

And the line number is pointing to the line:

```
->setParameter('conference', $conference);
```

When using

```
'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->where('s.conference = :conference')
        ->setParameter('conference', $this->conference);
    },
```

I am getting this error message:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Using $this when not in object context in..
```

Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your FormType __construct(), you have a mistake in the class variable name to set :

```
public function __construct($conference)
{
    $this->conference = $conference;
}
```

In the `query_builder` parameter, use a class variable for value, and prefix parameter name with a ':' in the DQL part :

```
$conference = $this->conference;
$builder->add('section', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'SciForumVersion2Bundle:Section',
        'label' => 'Section',
        'property' => 'name',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($conference) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->where('s.conference = :conference')
            ->setParameter('conference', $conference);
        },
));
```

Comment: Thank you PéCé, but in this case I am getting Using $this when not in object context in...

Comment: @Milos: That is expected. You need to `use` variable in order to pass it to `query_builder`. EDIT: Ah, @PéCé has already edited the answer ;)

Comment: @Milos I edited my post, you have to pass the variable to the anonymous function.

Comment: @jperovic, you're right, thanks for giving the input.

Answer (score -1):

I thin this line is producing error

```
->where('s.conference = $conference')
```

i would be like that

```
->where('s.conference = conference')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact, this was a type when i created the ticket, sorry for that, but even by changing this, it is not fixing the problem.